# how to hide/unhide window by process name or processid using VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, process, window

im trying to hide/unhide window process by name or PID i have tried

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function ShowWindow(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal nCmdShow As ShowWindowCommands) As Boolean
```

End Function

but `ShowWindowCommands` what is and how to find it ?

thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is many ways to do this the easiest one should be this :

'GENERAL IMPORT

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
```

'FORM CLASS DECLARATION

```
  <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function ShowWindow(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal nCmdShow As Integer) As Boolean
End Function
```

'then if you want to hide `firefox's` `window` :

```
 Dim mywindow As Integer
    Dim processRunning As Process() = Process.GetProcesses()
    For Each pr As Process In processRunning
        If pr.ProcessName = "Firefox" Then
            mywindow = pr.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32()
            ShowWindow(mywindow , 0)
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: if showWindow(myWindow,0) is one way to hide,
how about to make it appeared as normal? is it just changing 0 to 1 ? @K3rnel31

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
Form.FromHandle(Process.GetProcessById(PID).MainWindowHandle).Show()
```

Comment: @K3rnel31 You're right. As the question didn't mention otherwise I assumed it was a local form within the application.